# Nextcloud : Changes In Synchronized Folders Not Being Tracked Reliably

Tags: 20.04, sync, nextcloud

I use nextcloud-desktop (version 3.3.6) from ppa:nextcloud-devs/client repositories on Ubuntu 20.04.

Every time I start the software, the notification about “Changes In Synchronized Folders Not Being Tracked Reliably” appears.

I tried the solution explained in the [Nextcloud FAQ](https://docs.nextcloud.com/desktop/2.6/faq.html#there-was-a-warning-about-changes-in-synchronized-folders-not-being-tracked-reliably) but it does not work.

I added :

fs.inotify.max_user_instances=8192

fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288

in the /etc/sysctl.conf file.

Do you have a solution please?

Dam’

Comment: How many files are being synchronised between your desktop and NextCloud, and how much memory does your system have to work with?

Comment: There are 6660 files in Nextcloud. I have 8GB on the computer. (I don't have this notification message on Windows.)

Comment: Comparing Ubuntu to Windows is like comparing Betelgeuse (the star) to Elon Musk (the human). Both exist in this universe ... and that's about where the similarities end. With fewer than 100K files, your NextCloud application shouldn't be complaining so much. Have you confirmed that NextCloud (the server) and the NextCloud client are both up to date? I've been seeing a lot of annoying failures lately as NextCloud Server is refusing to connect to any client that is 2+ weeks behind the release schedule ...

Comment: Server version : 21.0.3.1 / Client version : 3.3.6